# symmetric matrix can be written as a matrix exponential of symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

If I have a symmetric matrix $\boldsymbol{B} = e^{\boldsymbol{\Theta}t}e^{\boldsymbol{\Theta}^{T}t}$ where $\boldsymbol{\Theta}$ is a matrix with transpose  $\boldsymbol{\Theta}^{T}$, is it possible to say that $\boldsymbol{B} = e^{\boldsymbol{\alpha}t}$ where $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is also a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Is $\Theta$ symmetric? Is it normal?

Comment: Hello, no $\boldsymbol{\Theta}$ is any square constant matrix, and has no particular properties apart that it is real

Comment: $e^Xe^Y=e^{X+Y}$  so $\alpha = \Theta +\Theta^T$

Comment: @saulspatz:  this only holds if $XY = YX$.

Comment: @saulspatz this is only true when $X$ and $Y$ commute, which is precisely when $\Theta$ is normal.

Comment: This works only if they commute, however, I would like to probe this if $\boldsymbol{\Theta}$ does not commute with its transpose. Perhaps I could say that since $\boldsymbol{B}$ is symmetric, then it can be decomposed as $\boldsymbol{B} = \boldsymbol{P}\boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{P}^{-1}$ where $\boldsymbol{D}$ is a diagonal matrix and then $\boldsymbol{D} = e^{\boldsymbol{U}}$ but I would need all elements of $\boldsymbol{D} \geq 0$. Could this always be the case?

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes, my mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: @Leo Thanks.  Careless of me.